# Capybara JS tests unable to access DB fixtures even after disabling transactions

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I just learned some time ago that Capybara spins up a separate server and DB connection for Javascript tests, which means DB data you set up in a `before` block is not available during the test.

As described in [this popular article](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/), the app is configured as follows to disable transactional fixtures

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.javascript_driver = :webkit
  end

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:deletion)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Ideally, this should use the `:deletion` approach on all JS enabled tests and avoids inserting data transactionally.

I tried it out with a simple test where the user fills out an incredibly simple registration form with their name and submits it.

```
describe "Registration Process" do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  before(:each) do
    # Logs a fake user in and sets the session store so `current_user` in the Controller calls this user
    sign_in(user)
    visit registration_path
  end

  describe "Registration Form", js: true do
    before(:each) do
      fill_in :name, with: "Julio Jones"
      click_button("Submit")
    end


    it "sets the user's name" do
      expect(user.reload.name).to eq("Julio Jones")
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the controller action that's called when the form is submitted. Pretty simple -

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    current_user.update(name: params[:name])
  end
end
```

My problem is that inside the Controller, it's unable to see the `User` record in the DB at all

1. If I pause the execution in the spec `before` block, I can see 1 `User` record created so far (`User.count` = 1).
2. If I pause execution inside the code being tested (i.e. the Controller action), I **can** see the `User` object (`current_user.present?` is `true`) but I **can not** see the record in the DB (`User.count` = 0)

This tells me that the `User` model object is being stored and retrieved correctly, but it's using a different DB connection because there's no physical backing record stored in the DB table.

Even stranger, I can confirm that it's **not** running transactionally.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.open_transactions # => 0
```

Any thoughts on what else could be blocking it from seeing the DB records? Does it have anything to do with using `:webkit` as the Javascript driver? I know most examples I've seen online use `:selenium`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a guess how to debug if what capybara and server sees match. Try to output to the view database records. It's just a guess, but i think this way you may catch mismatch in capybara and server db state.

I actually had same issue but i use minitest. Are you sure DatabaseCleaner commands executed in right order? try to `.start` it explicitly in:

```
config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion
    DatabaseCleaner.start
end
```

In my case it was already started with transaction strategy, so when you change strategy on the fly without `.start`ing it, DatabaseCleaner uses old strategy.